# How to replace a part of a string using Python3 if I don't have the exact string but a variable that contains it

Tags: python-3.x, string, web-scraping, replace, beautifulsoup

So, I have scraped a website http://quotes.toscrape.com/ as an assignment as part of a course and am creating a guessing game to guess the author of a quote. The game provides four guesses and in the last guess, I want to provide a sentence from the author's bio. Now, I have successfully requested this page and scraped the bio but I want to remove all instances of the author's name, last name and first name from the bio's description so that I can avoid giving the author's name in the last hint.

```
elif remaining_guesses == 1:
            bio_request = requests.get(f"{base_url}{random_quote['url']}")
            soup = BeautifulSoup(bio_request.text, "html.parser")
            description = soup.find(class_="author-description").get_text()
            desc_part = description.split(".")[4]
            name = random_quote["name"]
            print(type(name))

            if name in desc_part:
                desc_part.replace(name, "author")
            elif random_quote["name"].split(" ")[0] in desc_part:
                desc_part.replace(random_quote["name"].split(" ")[0], "author")
            elif random_quote["name"].split(" ")[1] in desc_part:
                desc_part.replace(random_quote["name"].split(" ")[1], "author")
            print(f"A hint from his bio: {desc_part}")
```

I am trying to use the replace() function but I am aware that I can't use it in this way by giving a variable as a string to replace so how can I replace the name, last name, or first name occurrences with for example "author".

Please let me know if I haven't been clear enough and I can even provide the entire code that I have. I was thinking of maybe the possibility of using regular expressions but I am not sure if that is the best fit. So, the problem is that I am doing a random pick of quotes each time as the game loops so I don't know the author's name, I can write it in the variable as I did with random_quote["name"] but the replace() needs an exact input, can I give it a variable input and say replace all instances of the variable if located in desc_part which is one sentence from the author's bio (in this case 5th sentence, but I might make it random, it doesn't matter). Here is an example of how the bio looks http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand your question right - but you can replace name(full, first, second) in whole text and then pick sentence at random.

For example:

```
import random
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from textwrap import wrap


url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/author/Albert-Einstein/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

name = 'Albert Einstein'
replaced_name = '*** REDACTED ***'
desc = soup.select_one('.author-description').get_text(strip=True, separator=' ')

# remove full name
desc = desc.replace(name, replaced_name)

# remove first name
desc = desc.replace(name.split()[0], replaced_name)

# remove last name
desc = desc.replace(name.split()[1], replaced_name)

print('\n'.join(wrap(desc)))

# pick random sentence
sentence = random.choice(desc.split('. '))
print()
print(sentence)
```

Prints:

```
In 1879, *** REDACTED *** was born in Ulm, Germany. He completed his
Ph.D. at the University of Zurich by 1909. His 1905 paper explaining
the photoelectric effect, the basis of electronics, earned him the
Nobel Prize in 1921. His first paper on Special Relativity Theory,
also published in 1905, changed the world. After the rise of the Nazi
party, *** REDACTED *** made Princeton his permanent home, becoming a
U.S. citizen in 1940. *** REDACTED ***, a pacifist during World War I,
stayed a firm proponent of social justice and responsibility. He
chaired the Emergency Committee of Atomic Scientists, which organized
to alert the public to the dangers of atomic warfare.At a symposium,
he advised: "In their struggle for the ethical good, teachers of
religion must have the stature to give up the doctrine of a personal
God, that is, give up that source of fear and hope which in the past
placed such vast power in the hands of priests. In their labors they
will have to avail themselves of those forces which are capable of
cultivating the Good, the True, and the Beautiful in humanity itself.
This is, to be sure a more difficult but an incomparably more worthy
task . . . " ("Science, Philosophy and Religion, A Symposium,"
published by the Conference on Science, Philosophy and Religion in
their Relation to the Democratic Way of Life, Inc., New York, 1941).
In a letter to philosopher Eric Gutkind, dated Jan. 3, 1954, ***
REDACTED *** stated: "The word god is for me nothing more than the
expression and product of human weaknesses, the Bible a collection of
honorable, but still primitive legends which are nevertheless pretty
childish. No interpretation no matter how subtle can (for me) change
this," (The Guardian, "Childish superstition: *** REDACTED ***'s
letter makes view of religion relatively clear," by James Randerson,
May 13, 2008). D. 1955.While best known for his mass–energy
equivalence formula E = mc2 (which has been dubbed "the world's most
famous equation"), he received the 1921 Nobel Prize in Physics "for
his services to theoretical physics, and especially for his discovery
of the law of the photoelectric effect". The latter was pivotal in
establishing quantum theory.*** REDACTED *** thought that Newtonion
mechanics was no longer enough to reconcile the laws of classical
mechanics with the laws of the electromagnetic field. This led to the
development of his special theory of relativity. He realized, however,
that the principle of relativity could also be extended to
gravitational fields, and with his subsequent theory of gravitation in
1916, he published a paper on the general theory of relativity. He
continued to deal with problems of statistical mechanics and quantum
theory, which led to his explanations of particle theory and the
motion of molecules. He also investigated the thermal properties of
light which laid the foundation of the photon theory of light.He was
visiting the United States when Adolf Hitler came to power in 1933 and
did not go back to Germany. On the eve of World War II, he endorsed a
letter to President Franklin D. Roosevelt alerting him to the
potential development of "extremely powerful bombs of a new type" and
recommending that the U.S. begin similar research. This eventually led
to what would become the Manhattan Project. *** REDACTED *** supported
defending the Allied forces, but largely denounced the idea of using
the newly discovered nuclear fission as a weapon. Later, with Bertrand
Russell, *** REDACTED *** signed the Russell–*** REDACTED ***
Manifesto, which highlighted the danger of nuclear weapons. ***
REDACTED *** was affiliated with the Institute for Advanced Study in
Princeton, New Jersey, until his death in 1955.His great intellectual
achievements and originality have made the word "*** REDACTED ***"
synonymous with genius.More: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/*** REDACTED
***_E...http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prize...
```

And random sentence:

```
*** REDACTED ***, a pacifist during World War I, stayed a firm proponent of social justice and responsibility
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but you can do this:

```
name= "Albert Einstein"
name_parts=name.split()
scraped_data=scraped_data.replace(name, "Author")
for i in name_parts:
   scraped_data=scraped_data.replace(i, "Author")
```

I am not sure if this helps. If they are using "Mr." or something like that then you can also add that case in the same loop. Whatever it is, Do let me know :D best of luck!